# How to correct this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Question: Which is incorrect? "***The continental shelf*** is ***the shadow area*** of the ***ocean floor*** that is ***closest to*** the continents."

The answer is "closest to", I asked my teacher but she didn't know why. Can anyone explain it to me?

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm fine with "closest to" in this context. I have more of a problem with "shadow area"; I have no idea what that's supposed to mean.

Comment: "the shadow area" is my answer but it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continental shelf is the **shallow** area of the ocean floor that is closest to the continents.

Most oceans, an exception being the Mediterraneum, have relatively flat shallow areas near their coasts.  At there edge there is usually a steep decline into the ocean depths. Fish thrive on continental shelves.  The Mediterraneum has never been a rich source of fish.